# How do i get from $x^{(\log(x))}=10000 $ to $\log(x)^2=\log(10000)$

Tags: logarithms

I'm looking at the solution for a math problem I'm trying to solve and can't comprehend the following step:

From:
$$
x^{\log_{10}(x)}=10000
$$
To:
$$
{\log_{10}(x)}^2=\log_{10}(10000)
$$
Is there a specific rule how this step works or is it just some kind of logarithmic logic?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might prove useful in the future for typesetting questions and anwers.

Comment: Thanks, just corrected it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$x^{\log_{10}(x)}= (10^{\log_{10}(x)})^{\log_{10}(x)} = 10^{\log_{10}(x)\cdot\log_{10}(x)}$$

Can you take it form here?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from the first to the second step.
Is there a law for this?
Or can you break it down into substeps?

Comment: Yes, there is a law: $a=b^{\log_b(a)}$.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. So we substitute the base x with $$10^{\log_{10}(x)}$$
And because we can multiply the exponents we get log(x)^2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Specfic rule is the power law
$$
a^b = c\,\,\text{taking logs}\\
\log \left(a^b\right) = b\log (a) = \log c
$$
now if you had $b = \log_{10} (a)$ what do you get?